# How to convert nested list to JSON object with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Here is the data structure of the jwt claims map, please see the `roles` is a list and the number of field/claim is not definite so I can't create POJO for it

```
// each name: value pair is a claim with its value, "R"
{
    "id": "someId",
    "jobTitle": "jobTitle",
    "age": "54",
    "roles": [
        "admin",
        "reader"
     ],
    "isLocked": "false"

    ...... // dynamic amount of extra fields
}
```

Then I use `Gson().toJson()` with `TypeToken`

```
String claimsMapInJsonString= new Gson().toJson(jwt.getClaims(), new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
```

However, the converted `claimsMapInJsonString` has following value for role

```
"roles":{"values":["admin","reader"]},
```

Thus the `"values"` become a block to deserialize the String into JSON object and treat role as a list. Any advice to this problem is appreciated

Comment: Have you looked into what `jwt.getClaims()` really consists of? I tried to parse the given JSON string into `Map<String,Object>`, then printed it out and the value type of field `roles` was an `ArrayList` and converting it back to JSON resulted in the correct output. My guess is that whatever created the `jwt` object, the result is not as desired.

Comment: Adding to what jCoder wrote; what is the Java class of your roles list? Are you using Android and the roles value is a `org.json.JSONArray`? That class is not supported by Gson, you have to use Gson's variant `com.google.gson.JsonArray` instead.