# GSON convert String to JSON with url in the value

Tags: java, json, gson

I converted a Map object to String with `toString()` method. However, it striped double quotes from each key and value

```
{title=mytitle, iss=https://google.com}
instead of 
{"title"="mytitle", "iss"="https://google.com"}
```

Then when I tried to convert it to JSON object with `GSON`,

```
Map<String, ? extends Object> objectMap= GSON.fromJson(myMap.toString(), Map.class);
```

it encountered.

```
Unterminated object at line 1 column 34 path $.
```

where I can see is the forward slash that caused the issue

Is there any API or function I can use to keep the double quote when convert map object to string or any method to let GSON avoid the `/` validation? I tried `setLient()` but it didn't work.

**Edit**:
The reason I can't use `GSON.toJson(object)` is because this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77455730/how-to-convert-nested-list-to-json-object-with-gson) GSON parse the array as TreeMap due to the extra `values` under the `role` entry

Comment: The proper solution here is still to use `Gson.toJson`. Using `Object.toString` gives you a human-readable output without any guarantees that it can be parsed properly again. You should rather try to solve the issue that there is an extra `values` member, as mentioned in your linked other question, than trying to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I converted a Map object to String with `toString()` method. However, it striped double quotes from each key and value ..."*

Note, these structures are not interchangeable to begin with.
Only a *[JSON object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)* would be considered a *map*, or *dictionary*.

Additionally, a *Map* uses an *equal-sign*, rather than a *colon*, for each *entry*.

If the *JSON* is simple, just implement your own.

Here is an example.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : m.entrySet()) {
    if (!s.isEmpty()) s.append(", ");
    s.append("\"%s\": \"%s\"".formatted(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
}
s.insert(0, '{').append('}');
```

Output

```
{"title": "mytitle", "iss": "https://google.com"}
```

Comment: Manually creating a JSON string like this should be avoided, especially if you are already using a JSON library anyway. For these simple values it might work, but if in the future they contain any characters which need to be escaped, then this will break; or depending on the use case could be exploited by a malicious user. OP should really use `Gson.toJson`, and as mentioned [in their other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77455730) find out where the extra `values` is coming from.

Comment: @Marcono1234, that's a bit extraneous. I mean, they might write their code wrong too.  There's an _RFC_ for _JSON_, check it out, _https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259_.

Comment: It is not extraneous. If you have a look at the other question of OP, you will see they ask this in the context of a JWT, so this has most likely a security aspect. Run your code with `var m = Map.of("title", "mytitle\",\"sub\":\"admin")` and you suddenly injected a `"sub":"admin"` entry in the JSON. Yes these JSON libraries might contain bugs, but Gson is more than 10 years old and has lots of unit tests, so the chance that it got escaping on JSON serialization wrong is quite low.